# Dereferencing Non-Pointers in C: n-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, n-dimensional

I was wondering if it is possible to reach the lowest level (the non-pointer level) of an n-dimensional array in C by conditionally dereferencing different layers of pointers until you reach a layer that is not pointers, as in the following example:

```
if(i_is_a_pointer){
  for(i = 0; i < some_given_length; i++){
    if((*i)_is_a_pointer){
      for(j = 0; j < some_given_length; j++){
        if((**i)_is_a_pointer)...etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which would delve through the array either until it hit a non-pointer or exhausted the final block of code written.  How would one go about, in C, determining if the thing is a pointer (I would guess that sizeof would work, if the target non-pointer were of a different size than the memory address), and would the statement **i be a compile-time or run-time error if *i were not itself a pointer?

Additionally, which languages and techniques do you use/would you recommend for traversing the non-array elements of an n-dimensional array, where n is determined at run-time?

Comment: C is a good language at traversing n demensional arrays. It will take a bit of pracice using dynamically allocated sizes, but it can be a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays in C aren't, as you seem to infer, nests of pointers until you reach the final level. They are just blocks of data.  Outer dimensions automatically convert to pointers in certain contexts: The array converts to a pointer to its first element. For example,

```
int a[3][4][5];
```

can also be written

```
typedef int INNER[5];    // array of 5 ints
typedef INNER MIDDLE[4]; // array of 5 INNERs (not pointers)
typedef MIDDLE OUTER[3]; // array of 3 MIDDLEs (not pointers)
OUTER a;
```

Then these are also equivalent pointer conversions of arrays.

```
MIDDLE *pm = a;
INNER *pi = a[0];
int *p = a[0][0];
```

and

```
int (*pm)[4][5] = a;
int (*pi)[5] = a[0];
int *p = a[0][0];
```

And finally since C is statically typed, there is no way or need to analyze types at run time as you are trying to do with your `if` statements.  In a compiled C program, there is essentually no type information remaining.

Comment: I was under the impression that an array of arrays in C would be a pointer to the zeroth element of the array, which would itself be an array taking the form of a pointer to its own zeroth element, which would be some non-pointer thing.  Is this impression incorrect, or are you and I thinking about different meanings for the term "nest of pointers?"

Comment: In c, the allocation would be of one contiguous memory block for a multi-dimensional array. So if you had `int Coordinates[ 10 ][ 10  ][ 10 ]`, it is ONE pointer... to Coordinates[0][0][0], and passed around, because it was allocated as `int [ 10 * 10 * 10 ]`

Comment: @CosmicComputer, this impression is incorrect. What you describe is an  *emulation* of an N-dimensional array. A "real" 2-dimensional array in c is an "array of arrays".